# hash sum mismatch when updating ubuntu 10.10

Tags: update, ubuntu-10.10

i got this error when executing "apt-get update", and only this file failed to download.

```
Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.bz2    Hash Sum mismatch
Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

this error has been repeated for a while. how can i fix this?

i tried both the servers in my country, and the main server in the US. both give the same results. **i am not behind any cache server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can get rid of those errors by doing:

```
root@host:~# apt-get clean
root@host:~# cd /var/lib/apt
root@host:/var/lib/apt# mv lists lists.old
root@host:/var/lib/apt# mkdir -p lists/partial
root@host:/var/lib/apt# apt-get update
```

As I understand it, these errors occur mainly when you're behind a caching proxy.

Comment: i did as you said, and i got the following when running **at-get update**  W: GPG error: http://mirrors.163.com maverick-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
  what should i do?

Comment: My problem here is that I *choose* to be behind a caching proxy in order to expedite network installs without needing to run a local package mirror.  I'd much rather find a way to avoid these problems but still be able to cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's not their fault, the checksum from http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release matches the md5sum/sha1sum/sha256sum of http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.bz2.

Such checksum errors are often caused by a bad network connection. Have you set up some kind of caching server between your server and the Internet?